# Counting and Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, f.name
FROM companies c
INNER JOIN facilities f ON c.id = f.company
ORDER BY c.name DESC, f.name
```

I also want to retrieve a `COUNT()` of all `work_orders` (a table) that are `approved` (a column containing 0 or 1) for each row (each facility).

e.g, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM work_orders w WHERE w.facility = f.id AND w.approved = 1`

The result should look like

```
company | facility | count
--------------------------
goog    | ohio     | 2
goog    | cali     | 0
tekk    | cupertin | 0
```

As kind of a follow up, i'd also like to add another count column where `w.approved = 0`

Comment: Please post the structure of the `work_orders` table, and I'll improve my answer.

Comment: It just has an `id`, `facility` foreign key, and `approved` status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, f.name, COUNT(w.id) AS work_orders
FROM companies c
INNER JOIN facilities f ON c.id = f.company
-- LEFT JOIN used in case there are facilities with no work orders
LEFT JOIN work_orders w ON f.id = w.facility AND w.approved = 1
GROUP BY c.id, c.name, f.name
ORDER BY c.name DESC, f.name
```

To do multiple counts (approved or not):

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, f.name, 
  wapp.wo AS approved_work_orders,
  wnapp.wo AS non_approved_work_orders,
FROM companies c
INNER JOIN facilities f ON c.id = f.company
LEFT JOIN (SELECT facility, COUNT(*) AS wo FROM work_orders WHERE approved=1 GROUP BY facility) wapp ON f.id = wapp.facility
LEFT JOIN (SELECT facility, COUNT(*) AS wo FROM work_orders WHERE approved=0 GROUP BY facility) wnapp ON f.id = wnapp.facility
ORDER BY c.name DESC, f.name
```

Comment: This drastically reduces my result set. I still want all of the facilities to show up, just have '0' if they dont meet the work_order join condition

Comment: @ChrisG. Even with the `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Yeah, I'd actually want `ON f.id=w.facility AND w.approved =1`

Comment: Let me throw a wrench in here, what if I wanted to do ANOTHER count. `(COUNT(w.id) where w.approved = 0) as not_approved` something like that?

Comment: @ChrisG Then you'd need a subquery or a couple more joins. I'll add some ideas.

Comment: That will work but its incredibly slow. I went with a pivot query instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need a grouping on c.id and an if statement

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, f.name, IF(count(0)>0,1,0) 
FROM companies c
INNER JOIN facilities f ON c.id = f.company
LEFT JOIN work_orders w ON w.facility = f.id
GROUP BY f.id
ORDER BY c.name DESC, f.name
```